# What is the purpose of taking the largest number as an input when you are computing the largest value in a sequence?

Tags: c++

```
int main ()
{
    double largest; cin >> largest;
    double input;
    while (cin >> input)
    {
        if (input > largest)
        {
            largest = input;
        }
    }
}
```

Why are we taking largest as a user input when clearly that is what we want out of this code fragment?

Comment: Who said you should? Why don't you ask them?

Comment: `largest` is the largest value _seen so far_.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings   It's given in the textbook, c++ for everyone, and there was no apparent reason why you would add this line of code. If I remove it from this code snippet, it won't affect my code, right?

Comment: What textbook? Pretend I can't see the textbook in front of you....

Comment: After reading one value, it is clearly the largest. Of the run of this program it will be updated. Note, however, that this program incorrectly omits checking whether the initial read is actually successful. As is it doesn't use the value anyway but if it unconditionally printed `largest`, e.g., at the end of the program it may access uninitialized memory, thereby creating undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't set `largest` to *something*, you're going to have problems; having an unset stack value means `largest` has a garbage value and you'll get undefined behavior when you test `if (input > largest)`. So that's the worst option; you don't want nasal demons.

You *could* initialize it `-HUGE_VAL`, or `-DBL_MAX` if you must avoid infinities (`-std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity()` and `-std::numeric_limits<double>::max()` or `std::numeric_limits<double>::lowest()` if you like to use C++ includes to simplify; the C headers distribute the limits for different types across multiple headers), instead to get a hugely negative value that any input would be larger than, and the code would be mostly the same, with the main difference being what happens if the user fails to provide any input; with a constant initializer, `largest` would remain that value (it never gets reassigned), while with `cin` initialization, it would get whatever `cin` does when it fails to parse a value (IIRC, for C++11 and later, `0` gets stored, before C++11 it stores nothing and we're still in nasal demons land).

The primary reason to initialize it from `cin` is just for simplicity; when we've only taken one input, then that input is the largest *so far*. As we loop, `largest` will remain the largest *so far* as we update it on demand, and when the loop is over, the largest *so far* also happens to be the largest *overall*, and our result is already in an appropriately named variable.

Technically, initializing from `cin` is probably trivially faster (given it avoids an unnecessary comparison in the first loop where initializing to `-HUGE_VAL` requires that test), but that's almost certainly meaningless relative to all the other overhead involved (e.g. reading from a file handle and parsing it).

Answer (score 0):

You have to add more information for this question to be answered appropriately, but in this little code snippet, `largest` is acting as a kind of starting point for comparison between user input and the by now largest input.

Answer (score 0):

The code transfers the input value to the variable `largest`, provided it is larger than the previously input values.

But this cannot work with the first value, as there was no previous. The fix is to assign the first value to `largest` unconditionally. (This is a correct measure, as the largest among a list of a single value is that value.)

---

A variant is to initialize `largest` with the smallest possible value.

```
int main ()
{
    double largest= std::numeric_limits<double>::lowest();
    double input;
    while (cin >> input)
    {
        if (input > largest)
        {
            largest = input;
        }
    }
}
```

---

There is a slight difference between the two versions: the first will require at least one value before it can exit. The second does not, and in case no value is input, it will return the smallest possible `double`.

Comment: This is subtly incorrect; `std::numeric_limits<double>::min()` is equivalent to `DBL_MIN`, which is the "minimum normalized *positive* value" of a `double`. It's first value *above* `0` after excluding denormal values, not "arbitrarily huge negative value", so by using it, the code can never produce a `largest` value less than or equal to zero, even if every input is negative. You'd want either `-std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity()` (note leading `-` to make it negative) or (for smallest finite `double`) `-std::numeric_limits<double>::max()` (again, leading `-` important).

Comment: @ShadowRanger: you are right. I will go for `lowest`, because I don't like `infinity` and at least conceptually, there is no guarantee that the smallest negative is the opposite of the largest positive.